# Drupal 7 making image link. wont show image?

Tags: php, drupal-7

I'm trying to make an image link but my image file wont show can anyone help? Thanks

Here's my code

```
function linking_module_basic(){
    $content = array();

    $variables = array(
    'path' => 'sites\all\modules\tshirt.png',
    'alt' => t('Click to create new shirt'),
    'title' => t('Create shirt'),
    );

    $content['themed_data'] = array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => theme('image', $variables),
        '#prefix' => '<div class = "linking-module-image"><a href = "https://www.facebook.com/">',
        '#suffix' => '</div></a>',
        '#attached' => array(
            'css' => array(
                drupal_get_path('module', 'linking_module') . '/linking_module.css',
            ),
        ),
    );

    return $content;
}
```

Here's my hook_menu

```
      function linking_module_menu() {

        $items = array();

        $items['linking'] = array(
        'title' => 'A Linking module',
        'page callback'  => 'linking_module_basic',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),


    );
    return $items;

  }
```

I cant seem to figure this out.

Comment: How and where are you calling the function 'linking_module_basic'

Comment: @prabeengiri ive already edited my post... hope you could help tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your problem!!. Drupal was encoding the image path!!

On your `path` value for image, change the back slash to forward slash and also add the base path.

```
function linking_module_basic(){
    $content = array();

    $variables = array(
    'path' => base_path() . 'sites/all/modules/tshirt.png',
    'alt' => t('Click to create new shirt'),
    'title' => t('Create shirt'),
    );

    $content['themed_data'] = array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => theme('image', $variables),
        '#prefix' => '<div class = "linking-module-image"><a href = "https://www.facebook.com/">',
        '#suffix' => '</div></a>',
        '#attached' => array(
            'css' => array(
                drupal_get_path('module', 'linking_module') . '/linking_module.css',
            ),
        ),
    );

    return $content;
}
```

It should work now as long as you have the image in the specified path!!.